# Chromecast and Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to wrap my head around a Chromecast project.  I don't have any Android, or Chrome extensions experience.  Looking through the documentation it seems that I need to build a Chrome extension that 'casts' images to the Chromecast via Javascript and HTML5.

Project concept is to send dynamic formats with images and video to a TV screen from a desktop.

Is it correct that HTML5 pages have to be built and casted to the TV?

Is there any other languages that involved in the process besides HTML5 and Javascript?

Can I use any web server to host the html pages, or do you have to use the node.js I've been reading about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver that you will write to run on chromecast is an html5 page with css and javascript. The data you send to the receive, among other things, should have references to the urls of the images and videos that you want to show there; those content can be served from any type of web server; chromecast doesn't care if it is served via apache or node.js or your own hand-crafted web server. To get a better understanding of the architecture, in general, you might want to consult our [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers).